# Chart.js - how to add a second data line to the line graph

Tags: chart.js

How to add a second data line to the line graph:

```
        var config = {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: ["28/01/2018 15:07:34", "28/02/2018 12:31:27", "28/05/2018 01:21:28", "27/10/2018 01:21:28", "28/11/2018 05:09:28"],
                datasets: [{
                        label: "title",
                        backgroundColor: "transparent",
                        borderColor: "#000",
                        data: [65, 76, 32, 54, 43]
                    }]
            },
            options: {
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        tension: 0
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: { },                    
            }
        };
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

containing data:

```
labels: ["28/01/2018 15:07:34", "28/05/2018 01:21:28", "27/10/2018 01:21:28" ],  data: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

I would also like the lines between the dots to have the colors red, black, red, black. I do not know how to do this.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.2.1 of Chart js;

```
myChart.data.datasets[myChart.data.datasets.length] = {
  label: "",
  xAxisID: "x-axis-2",
  data: newDataArray.map((val, index) => {x: labels[i], y: val}),
  fill: false,
  backgroundColor: "",
  borderColor: "",
  borderWidth: 1
}
myChart.update();
```

`myChart.data.datasets.length` can be set if you know the specific number of datasets(lines) you're working with.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this in-line (you already have the data), you would add it to the "datasets" thus:

```
data: {
    labels: ["28/01/2018 15:07:34", "28/02/2018 12:31:27", "28/05/2018 01:21:28", "27/10/2018 01:21:28", "28/11/2018 05:09:28"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "title",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        borderColor: "#000",
        data: [65, 76, 32, 54, 43]
    },{
        label: "title2",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        borderColor: "#000",
        data: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
    }]
},
```

If you want to add data after the fact, you would push the dataset onto the data array as outlined here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Comment: Actually what he means is to add a completely new dataset to the current chart, not to add a single item to the current dataset